# Extract features from text file and train them to classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to organize some data from a text file into features for the classifier. I have 3 features to train and I'm having some troubles in understanding what is the correct format for a feature variable.

```
from sklearn import tree
import os
import re

os.chdir(r"C:\ig_automation")
metrics_to_train = open('metrics_to_train.txt', 'r')
labels_to_train = open('labels_to_train.txt', 'r')
validation_metrics = open('validation_metrics.txt', 'r')
validation_labels = open('validation_labels.txt', 'r')

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
features = metrics_to_train.read().replace("\n","").replace("   "," 
").split(" ")
print(features)
```

Output:

```
['1434.0', '4000000.0', '33.0', '82.0', '39.0', '219.0', '634.0', '5506.0', '58.0', '106.0', '783.0', '332.0', '222.0', '413.0', '197.0', '112.0'......
```

The data is as follows: feat 1 - number of posts(pos 0 = 1434), feat 2 - followers(pos 1 = 4000000), feat 3 - number of follows(pos 2 = 33) and it repeats until the last value of the list.

I have to train the classifier with this features and get one label.

And also if there is any problem with how I've imported the data, here are some lines from the text file:

```
1434.0   4000000.0   33.0   
82.0   39.0   219.0   
634.0   5506.0   58.0   
106.0   783.0   332.0   
222.0   413.0   197.0
```

I'm kind of new at ML so, I would really need some advice. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, each line in the text file corresponds to one example, i.e. the first line is all features for 1 user, the second line is features for the 2nd user, and so on. If that is the case the way you are reading the data is incorrect. You should get (N x 3) matrix, where N is the number of users, 3 is the number of features (posts, followers, follows).

Comment: Yes, the data is displayed how you described. I will try it out, thanks!

Comment: It worked! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transpose the feature matrix.

The reason of this is that all `scikit-learn` functions are expecting a matrix `X` as input where the rows are the `subjects(samples)` and the columns are the `features(variables)?.

From the [documentation:](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)

[image]

So, **transpose** the data using `numpy` as a fast way:

```
import numpy as np

features = np.array(features)
X = features.T

clf.fit(X,....)
```